# How to find key in Gemfire

Tags: gemfile, geode

How to find inside Gemfire region, what column defined  as key during data load ?

List and describe is not giving required info

Example i am.looking something smiler to oracke "ALL_CONSTRAINTS" where you can run following sql to find primary key

```
        SELECT a.COLUMN_NAME
                FROM all_cons_columns a INNER JOIN 
               all_constraints c 
              ON a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name 
                    WHERE c.table_name = 'TBL'
                     AND c.constraint_type = 'P'
```

- https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/list.html
- https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/describe.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found , please find correct solution here

```
         query --query="select * from /region_name.keySet()"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about what you mean by *find inside Region*, but my guess is that you're trying to find wether a particular entry exists within a given GemFire region.

If that's the case, then you can use the [get](https://gemfire-98-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html#get-java.lang.Object-) method from the [Region](https://gemfire-98-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html) class. If you want to use [GemFire SHell](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/gemfire/tools_modules/gfsh/chapter_overview.html) directly instead of a custom Java application, on the other hand, you can use the [get command](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/get.html). Last, but not least, you could also execute a [OQL query](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/developing/querying_basics/chapter_overview.html) with the [query command](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/98/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/query.html), as an example: `query --query="SELECT e.value FROM /MyRegion.entries e WHERE e.key='myKey'"`

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: GemFire is an in-memory data store, not a RDBMS system. That said, keep in mind that there are no "columns" within a GemFire region, just plain old java objects with different attributes. It's entirely your choice what to use as the region `key`, sometimes the actual `key` doesn't even belong to the object used as the value. In summary, the answer to your question would be no.

Comment: How to get all keys where value field value matches?